# Help learning how to create tile based games in java and or C#

Tags: 2d

I want to get into 2d based gaming design and creation however, I really do not know where to start. I know java and c# but not how to use them in an efficient way. I'd like to create 2d tile based games such as mario or pokemon. Is there a good place to learn how to do this?

thanks,

Euden

Comment: Euden, Welcome to GameDev! Unfortunately this type of broad question is not really the type of question that's suited for this site. If you read the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) you'll see that. Check out some tutorials and good luck!

Comment: -1 for being vague, but try out http://gamedev.net

Comment: Here is a [Youtube series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvie2SLwVOw&feature=youtube_gdata) - can't see if it's any good as I am at work (Youtube is blocked).

Comment: Looks like it's a useful youtube series.

Answer (score 1):

Even though your question is a bit abstract, I myself had the same question some time ago.

This is what I consult you to do:
First of all, try making a small game, like a board game. I for example did my version of [Reversi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi), in Java. Later on I moved to [Snake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_%28video_game%29). And now I'm developing my own maze based dungeon game.

Try [this](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/) site to see some examples of some 2d games made in Java.

**Edit:**
A quick google search led me [here](http://www.gamespp.com/cgi-bin/index.cgi?sourcecode), where you can view the source code of a "super mario" like game in C.

Hope it helps.